# Using #!/usr/bin/expect and bash

Tags: bash, expect

Is there any way I can use bash script along with /usr/bin/expect commands?

Could I, for instance, use an if statement in a usr/bin/expect script?

Comment: zero effort? google for `expect language if`.

Comment: If you really want **bash**, as opposed to TCL, then I'd suggest using emPTY instead of Expect: http://empty.sf.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expect` is an extension of `tcl` - therefore you can use the programming constructs of `tcl` - these include 'if'.

Tcl command man pages are available: [tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/contents.htm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/contents.htm)

Comment: Thanks - have added reference to the answer

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very simple script that connects to a server via ssh from bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
    spawn ssh user@server
    expect {
        "assword:" {
            send -- "1234\r"
        }
    }
EOF
```

Comment: I would really recommend reading **Exploring Expect** by Don Libes

Comment: Note that it simply connects, then the ssh session dies when the expect script ends: it does not leave you connected to the server when the bash script resumes.